# How do I start my service at boot-time?

Tags: netbsd, init

I'm trying to run a CherryPy app on my NetBSD 5.1 box. To have it start automatically, I've added this line to my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/bin/httpd &
```

When I boot the machine, some of the output of the Webserver starting is visible, right after the `Starting sshd.` message. None the less, I can't connect to my web-server.

I can log into the machine, and when I start the web-server by typing `httpd`, it all works well. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to have my program start on boot-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program will exit as soon as the `rc.local` script is finished. So, here's the complete procedure that doesn't require the program to understand any of the rc.d stuff:

- Make the script executable (e.g. `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/httpd`)
- Add the following line to your `/etc/rc.local`:

  ```
  nohup /usr/local/bin/httpd &
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add `httpd=YES` to `/etc/rc.conf`. Reading `man rc.conf` might help

Comment: thanks for telling me to read the manual :-) Now, I'm using rc.local rather than rc.conf, as the NetBSD guide says: "to start local daemons that don't fit the rc.d model". So I'm afraid your answer doesn't help me in this case.